# Search solution for a file loader using buttons

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to load BVH files via button. I use the three.js BVHLoader. I can easily load a single file, but if I want to load many different ones, it will not work. The following code is an example of what that looks like. Is there a simple solution to do that? Thanks!

```js
var url;
  
 BVHclip1.onclick = function url() {  
 url = "Clip000.bvh";  
 }
 BVHclip2.onclick = function url() {  
 url = "Clip002.bvh";
 }
   
var loader = new THREE.BVHLoader();
var path = "three/models/BVH/" +  url;    
//var path = "three/models/BVH/Clip000.bvh";  //< -- this is running
 loader.load( path, function( result ) {
  
//Example 2//

        BVHclip1.onclick = function url() {  
 url = "three/models/BVH/Clip000.bvh";  
 }
 BVHclip2.onclick = function url() {  
 url = "three/models/BVH/Clip002.bvh";
  }
  
var loader = new THREE.BVHLoader();
 loader.load( url, function( result ) {
```

```html
<button id="BVHclip1" onclick="BVHclip1()">Animation_1</button>   
<button id="BVHclip2" onclick="BVHclip2()">Animation_2</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you provide looks incomplete (see `Uncaught SyntaxError` when trying to run it), but I think the issue is this: keep in mind that when you write...

```
var url;
el.onclick = function () {
  url = 'hey';
}
console.log(url);
```

... `url` is not actually set until the click happens, by which point the `console.log` has already printed `undefined`. You're making the same mistake with `url` here.

Instead, use a function:

```
var loadURL = function (url) {

  var loader = new THREE.BVHLoader();
  loader.load(url, function (result) {
    // ...
  });

};

var clip1El = document.querySelector('#BVHclip1');
clip1El.addEventListener('click', function () {
  loadURL("three/models/BVH/Clip000.bvh");
});

var clip2El = document.querySelector('#BVHclip2');
clip2El.addEventListener('click', function () {
  loadURL("three/models/BVH/Clip002.bvh");
});
```

Comment: @ Don McCurdy many thank's for the professional help. It works now everything. Great explanation A++